# testing services in nodejs with sinon chai & mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon-chai

i'm tring to test my bycrptSevice...
here my service:

```
module.exports = (bcrypt) => {
  const hashKey = Number(process.env.BCRYPT_HASH_KEY) || 10;

  function checkPassword(reqPassword, userPassword) {
    console.log("bycrptService: checkPassword call()");

    return bcrypt.compareSync(reqPassword, userPassword);
  }

  function createHashPassword(password) {
    console.log("bycrptService: createHashPassword call()");

    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, hashKey);
  }

  return {
    checkPassword,
    createHashPassword
  };
}
```

this is the test file:

```
const { assert, should, expect, sinon } = require('../baseTest');

const bcryptService = require('../../services/bcryptService');
const bcryptjs = require('bcryptjs');

describe('bcryptService Tests', function() {
    const bcrypt = bcryptService(bcryptjs);
    let Password = '1234';
    let crptPassword = bcrypt.createHashPassword(Password);

    it('test the createHashPassword() create new hash password to the input password',function(){
      expect(crptPassword).to.not.be.equal(Password);
    })

    it('test the checkPassword() check if return true when its compere and false when its not', function() {
       bcrypt.checkPassword(Password,crptPassword).should.be.true;
       bcrypt.checkPassword('987',crptPassword).should.be.false;
    })
    it('test onInit bycrptSevice shoud have hashKey',function(){
     //how to check it??? 
    })
});
```

my first question is: how could i check if hashKey exist?
secondly: shoud i test it? i mean - its my responsibility to check it or maybe i don't be care about privete field
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to test the hashKey you must export it in your `bycrptSevice` and then you can do whatever tests you want to it.

Regarding your second question, it depends, but for your case, the `hashkey` is an environment variable, and you should setup it before running your tests, so its not necessary to test it.